# Select minimum value from head and tail of a column - Perl

Tags: perl

Following is a code for distance of each residue from the center of mass of a protein.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $chain = 'A';
my $s1 = 0;
my $s2 = 0;
my $s3 = 0;

my $cx=0;
my $cy=0;
my $cz=0;

my @pdb;
while(<>){
    my @col = split;
    next unless $col[0] eq 'ATOM' and $col[4] eq $chain;
    push @pdb, [@col[2,3,5,6,7,8]];
}

for (my $i=0;$i<=$#pdb;$i++){
    my($a, $r, $n, $x, $y, $z) = @{$pdb[$i]};

    $s1 = $s1+$x;
    $cx++;

    $s2 = $s2+$y;
    $cy++;

    $s3 = $s3+$z;
    $cz++;
}

my $X = sprintf "%0.3f", $s1/$cx;
my $Y = sprintf "%0.3f", $s2/$cy;
my $Z = sprintf "%0.3f", $s3/$cz;

#distance of every atom from COM.

for my $j(0..$#pdb){
    my($a1, $r1, $n1, $x1, $y1, $z1) = @{$pdb[$j]};
    my $dist = sprintf "%0.3f", sqrt(($X-$x1)**2 + ($Y-$y1)**2 + ($Z-$z1)**2);
    if($a1 eq 'CA'){
        &rmin($dist,"\n");
    }
}
sub rmin{
    my @pdb1 = @_;
    print @pdb1;    
}
```

The subroutine `rmin` printing the distance of each residue from the COM as a column. I need to send the minimum value from the first 10 and last 10 distances into two separate variables. I have tried `head` and `tail` commands using backticks:

```
@res = `head -10` @pdb1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [List::Util's min](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#min) and a couple array slices should work:

```
use List::Util qw(min);

$smallest_of_first_ten = min @pdb1[0 .. 9];
$smallest_of_last_ten  = min @pdb1[-10 .. -1];
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me this module